# jquery check if image in anchor is equal to specific url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to check if image in anchor is equal to specific url. Here is html i have

```
<div class="gallery_images" id="2">
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" tabindex="0">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://v9contest.geojidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/contest_entries/thumbnail-^739D24706DC178C938623C638DDBFF0BC04ADF35338114AF68^pimgpsh_thumbnail_win_distr.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

so when page loads, i want to suppose check if link image in anchor is equal to http://google.com. Here what i tried

```
if(jQuery('a').has('img.img-fluid').attr('src')=='http://google.com'){ alert('ok'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the direct descendent selector, `>`, instead. Following is the working example:

```js
if (jQuery('a > img.img-fluid').attr('src') == 'http://google.com') {
  alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery_images" id="2">
  <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" tabindex="0">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://google.com">
  </a>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the selector may return more than one element if there are many such elements. In that case, you will need to loop through and check.

Comment: yes, there are multiple elements. its not working on my side

Comment: @Rizwi -- If there are multiple such elements, what's the criteria of showing the alert then?

Comment: @Rizwi maybe edit the question to show the *actual* html - as it is, no-one would expect more than one image as all the html and text you've provided is in the singular ("if link image in anchor is equal")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it is resoved. I used

```
jQuery('a > img.img-fluid').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr('src')=='http://google.com'){ alert('ok'); }
            });
```